# How to count a null value as 0 while using JOINS in Mysql database?

Tags: mysql, database, join, count, null

I have 2 tables as follows

Human

```
id name
1  John
2  mark
```

Computer

```
id human_id
1  2
2  null
```

I want my answer to be as following

```
name no_of_computer
John 0
mark 1
```

I tried the following but am wrong

```
select h.name,c.human_id) as 'no_of_computer' from human h
join 
computer c on c.human_id = h.id 
group by h.id
```

my code is not counting the null as 0 so its just avoiding that and only showing that mark has 1 computer, but I want to see John has 0 computer too. please help me out, thanks in advance

Comment: try `LEFT` join

Comment: Your published code is syntactically incorrect please correct.AND where did p.id come from?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery that's something like:

```
SELECT  
h.Name,
(SELECT COUNT(c.id_of_computers) 
FROM computers c
WHERE c.id_human = h.id) as no_of_computer
FROM humans h
```

Do not cut and paste this to test, as I paid no attention to actual ID names in your tables. You'll have to look at that.